# Ediff: compare two (long) buffers Word-by-word

Tags: ediff

I use Emacs 26.1 and try to compare two (long) buffers (opened side by side) by clicking Tools -> Compare (Ediff) -> Windows Word-by-word... Then I choose both Windows (A and B) by clicking on each opened buffer. However it looks like Emacs compares only the visible parts of the two buffers, not the whole buffers. Why?

I saw there is a command `ediff-windows-wordwise`... How is "Window" defined? - as "currently visible part of a buffer"? If yes, is there something like `ediff-buffers-wordwise`?

Update: 
I have `git` in `exec-path`, so maybe I can make ediff to display the output of `git diff --word-diff file1 file2` in ediff style?

Comment: According to my understanding, a *window* is the visible part of a buffer. If so, the command is doing the right thing!

Comment: If so, how do I compare two *complete buffers* word by word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ediff-regions-wordwise` for the whole buffers.
The input of the regions is a bit daunting though.

The following elisp snippet defines `ediff-buffers-wordwise` working like `ediff-buffers`. A caveat is that it uses the internal function `ediff-regions-internal`. So it might be that it does not work with future emacs versions. But that is not very likely.

You can copy the elisp snippet to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) if you want to use it.
`ediff-buffers-wordwise` is available after the next restart of Emacs or after reevaluating the init file.

```el
(eval `(defun ediff-buffers-wordwise (buffer-A buffer-B &optional startup-hooks job-name)
     ,(concat (documentation 'ediff-buffers) "\nComparison is done word-wise.")
     ,(interactive-form 'ediff-buffers)
     (setq bufA (get-buffer buffer-A)
           bufB (get-buffer buffer-B)
           job-name (or job-name 'ediff-buffers-wordwise))
     (cl-assert bufA nil
            "Not a live buffer: %s" buffer-A)
     (cl-assert bufB nil
            "Not a live buffer: %s" buffer-B)
     (ediff-regions-internal bufA
                 (with-current-buffer bufA
                   (point-min))
                 (with-current-buffer bufA
                   (point-max))
                 bufB
                 (with-current-buffer bufB
                   (point-min))
                 (with-current-buffer bufB
                   (point-max))
                 startup-hooks
                 job-name
                 'word-mode
                 nil)))

(require 'easymenu)

(easy-menu-add-item
 menu-bar-tools-menu
 '("Compare (Ediff)")
 ["Two Buffers Word-by-word..." ediff-buffers-wordwise t]
 "Three Files...")
```

Comment: It works very nice and fast actually! Could you, please, extend it so that a menu option "Tools -> Compare (Ediff) -> Buffers Word-by-word..." also appears... Thank you very  much!

Comment: FYI: I was told that `ediff-windows-wordwise` also relies on `ediff-regions-internal` internally, so your approach is consistent with the mainstream.

Comment: Update: while everything seems to work fine, I get an error message in the mini-buffer: `Args out of range: "nil", 6, nil` . What can this be?

Comment: @user1876484 I have corrected the problem with `Args out of range` and I have added the menu item.

Comment: Just excellent! Strange that it's not part of Emacs out of the box... Just for the sake of completeness: [the same for two files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46206/ediff-compare-two-files-word-by-word). Thank you!