# How to make a diff tool ignore asterisks?

Tags: org-mode, diff

I want to compare and merge some org files. How can I make a diff tool assume that some tasks or notes are identical, even if they are on different levels, i.e. strings only differ in the number of asterisks (*) at the beginning? I would then collapse those strings and consider merging only the rest that really differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can configure `ediff-filtered-filters` such that it replaces multiple leading stars with one leading star and call `ediff-buffers`.

The following Elisp function `my-org-ediff` does that for you. Just copy the Elisp code to your init file, restart Emacs, and use `my-org-ediff` for diffing org files in the way you want it.

```el
(defvar ediff-filtered-filters)
(defun my-org-ediff ()
  "Ediff like `ediff-buffers' but convert all heading leaders \\*+\\([[:space:]]\\) to \\*\\1."
  (interactive)
  (let ((ediff-filtered-filters '(("^\\*+\\([[:space:]]\\)" . "*\\1"))))
    (call-interactively #'ediff-buffers)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are content to use `diff` on the bash command line and are not looking for a pure emacs solution, you can use [process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe?answertab=active#tab-top) to pass into `diff` slightly modified files:

```
diff <(sed -E 's/^\*+/*/' file1.org) <(sed -E 's/^\*+/*/' file2.org)
```

Each `sed` command outputs its input file unchanged, except that a string of one or more asterisks at the beginning of a line is changed to a single asterisk. Bash process substitution makes a file out of that output. Conceptually, the above is equivalent to

```
sed -E 's/^\*+/*/' file1.org > /tmp/file1.modified.org
sed -E 's/^\*+/*/' file2.org > /tmp/file2.modified.org
diff /tmp/file1.modified.org /tmp/file2.modified.org
rm /tmp/file1.modified.org /tmp/file2.modified.org
```

You can also write a bash script to simplify the invocation:

```
#!/bin/bash

diff <(sed -E 's/^\*+/*/' $1) <(sed -E 's/^\*+/*/' $2)
```

Save it as `stardiff` in `$HOME/bin` (which I assume is in your `$PATH`), make it executable: `chmod +x $HOME/bin/stardiff` and invoke it like this:

```
stardiff file1.org file2.org
```

Process substitution is a general mechanism and is very useful in situations like this one, where we basically want to pipe the output of a command (the sed command output) into the input of another command (the diff command), except that we have two or more inputs: an ordinary pipe cannot deal with that, but process subsitution can.

Of course, this has nothing to do with emacs, but I hope the emacs SE moderators will not be too upset :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do an `ediff-buffers-wordwise` and type <kbd>#h</kbd> `\*+` to ignore words consisting of stars.

If you advance to the next diff by pressing  <kbd>SPC</kbd>  ediff will skip words only differing in the number of stars.

Comment: I cannot find a command "ediff-buffers-wordwise"

Comment: Same question for me. I guess that this is a custom function defined in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46195/226